# How best to safely, efficiently run code on the main queue in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

In objective-c, if I wanted to arrange for a block to run on the main queue, whether I was already on that queue, I could use the approach from Marco Arment's FCUtilities:

https://github.com/marcoarment/FCUtilities/blob/master/FCUtilities/FCBasics.m

Pre-swift 3, that approach could be reproduced as:

```
struct Static {
    static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
}

// If we're already on the main thread, just execute the block. Else, dispatch_async(..) it onto the main thread
func onMainThread(block: () -> ()) {
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        dispatch_queue_set_specific(dispatch_get_main_queue(), &Static.onceToken, &Static.onceToken, nil)
    }

    if (dispatch_get_specific(&Static.onceToken) == &Static.onceToken) {
        block()
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
    }
}
```

In a Swift 3 world, that's no longer valid. I'm currently of the belief that the `dispatch_get_specific` test is the best/safest way to decide whether to execute or dispatch the block, but am failing to port it to Swift 3. What would a Swift 3 solution be?

**Edit:**
Ok, it seems I was getting too hung up on *"this used to be (according to some) the way to do it, how do I port that to the new syntax?"* when the actual answer is far simpler : `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: I don't understand this code. Since the caller obviously doesn't care if the block is executed before the function returns (since it may be passed to `dispatch_async`), why not just *always* call `dispatch_async`? What is the use of `set_specific` achieving here?

Comment: If we want to push the block onto the main queue, it's most likely because it's going to modify the UI. If we're already on the main queue, we're probably already doing that, so we want the block to execute 'inline'. If we're not on the main queue, we're probably handling input from the network and are happy to dispatch_async(). The key point being, at the call point we don't necessarily know which case applies, but we just want it to DoTheRightThing. As for `set_specific`, it's a common pattern, but I don't know the origin. Presumably *best* approach, by some measure.

Comment: The question is: why do you care that it happens "inline" in this case? What behavior would be different than if you used `dispatch_async`. I'm familiar with this pattern when applied to `dispatch_sync`; Apple describes it as one to avoid (the docs now unambiguously say "Attempting to synchronously execute a work item on the main queue results in dead-lock"). But I've never seen it applied to `dispatch_async` since it doesn't really change much for you (since the caller obviously can't assume it'll be synchronous).

Comment: But in any case, DispatchQueue.getSpecific is available. What problem are you having? I assume the `dispatch_once_t`? You can now achieve that with a global variable with a closure initializer like `let once: Void = { ... }()` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, it's reproducing what the `dispatch_once_t` used to enable, but in this new `DispatchSpecific<T>` world.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725463/dispatch-once-conversion-swift-3

Comment: Unfortunately that just confuses me further. What am I lazy initialising, the key or the value? Or both? In the same initialiser? In which case, don't I need a temporary version of the struct that the initialiser can return, but then does the fact that a copy occurs matter?

Comment: Yeah; tried to build the whole thing. Apple broke other pieces that this requires (having nothing to do with dispatch_once). There is no "get specific for current queue" anymore. That's not surprising. They've been warning against these patterns for years and they'd already removed every other way to ask for "the current queue" (since it's not meaningful in the way people think it is). I don't think this can be built in Swift 3 (but it never actually worked in previous versions either; there have always been corner cases). This particular code should be replaced with just an async call.

Comment: The answer to "How best to safely, efficiently run code on the main queue in Swift 3" is definitely as simple call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`. That is safe and efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was getting too hung up on *"this used to be (according to some) the way to do it, how do I port that to the new syntax?"* when the actual answer is far simpler:

`DispatchQueue.main.async`